# Who loads the Facebook pixel script?

Tags: shopify, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

Our website is run on Shopify and both Shopify app(through app store app) and google tag manager tries to load [Facebook Pixel on my page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/meta-pixel/get-started).

Is there a way to know which javascript boostrapped my pixel script into the page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to tell which script injected an element from the page itself.

You can confirm if Google Tag Manager (GTM) is firing the tag buy using the preview tool in GTM.

You would want to find out what the tag is named in GTM. Then, use the preview tool to confirm whether the tag is fired.

You need to confirm if the tag shows in the "tags fired" or "tags not fired" section when the event occurs.

I don't know how to confirm if Shopify is adding the tag. I'm sure you can see if it is configured to include a pixel in the settings.

My suggestion is to rule out GTM using the method above.